# Looping over JavaScript array not producing correct results

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a program that should set a string answer to a specific value. I have tried reversing the order of the loop, setting global variables, but something is off in the way the arrays are being processed.

The code below

```
        console.log("The value of the dlArray is")
        console.log(dlArray)
        console.log("The value of the elArray is")
        console.log(elArray)
        dlArray = shuffle(dlArray);
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
            html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\'s';
            id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
            html += id;
            html +='\' class=\'draggyBox-small ui-draggable\'>\n';
            html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
            html += elArray[i-numberOfInputs]
            html += '\n';
            html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n';
        }
        console.log("The value of the dlArray is")
        console.log(dlArray)
        console.log("The value of the elArray is")
        console.log(elArray)

        function shuffle(a){
            for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
              j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
              if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
            }
            return a
        }
```

produces the Actual output

```
*****************************************
The value of the dlArray is
word_match.js:99 (4) ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
word_match.js:100 The value of the elArray is
word_match.js:101 (4) ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4']
word_match.js:113 The value of the dlArray is
word_match.js:114 (4) ['d4', 'd3', 'd1', 'd2']
word_match.js:115 The value of the elArray is
word_match.js:116 (4) ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4']
word_match.js:198 k1:d4 k2:d3 k3:d1 k4:d2
```

The expected output should be

```
*****************************************
The value of the dlArray is
word_match.js:99 (4) ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
word_match.js:100 The value of the elArray is
word_match.js:101 (4) ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4']
word_match.js:113 The value of the dlArray is
word_match.js:114 (4) ['d4', 'd3', 'd1', 'd2']
word_match.js:115 The value of the elArray is
word_match.js:116 (4) ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4']
word_match.js:198 k1:d1 k2:d2 k3:d3 k4:d4
```

Where is the error in this for loop coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not giving a lot of details, I would assume the `dlArray` is always in reverse order.

This would be another way of doing it without a for loop:

```js
const elArray = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'];
const dlArray = ['d4', 'd3', 'd2', 'd1'];

dlArray.reverse();

const answers = elArray.map((value, index) => `${value}:${dlArray[index]}`);

// Alternative without mutating the original dlArray
//
// const reversedDl = [...dlArray].reverse();
// const answers = elArray.map((value, index) => `${value}:${reversedDl[index]}`

console.log(elArray);
console.log(dlArray);
console.log(answers.join(' '));
```

**UPDATE**
After your changes to the original post, I understand that you need to sort the dlArray before doing it because it might be shuffled (?)

An updated version would be:

```js
const elArray = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'];
const dlArray = ['d3', 'd2', 'd1', 'd4'];

// Without mutating the original dlArray
const sortedDlArray = [...dlArray].sort();
const answers = elArray.map((value, index) => `${value}:${sortedDlArray[index]}`);

// Alternative with mutating the original dlArray
// dlArray.sort();
// const answers = elArray.map((value, index) => `${value}:${dlArray[index]}`);

console.log('elOriginal:', elArray);
console.log('dlOriginal:', dlArray);
console.log('dlSorted:', sortedDlArray);
console.log(answers.join(' '));
```

You may update the `${value}:${sortedDlArray[index]}` to include whatever classes you need there:

eg.

```
elArray.map(
    (value, index) => 
        `<div id="wrapper-${index}" class="whatever-class you need here">${value}:${sortedDlArray[index]}</div>`
);
```

Comment: I updated the answer. If that still does not work, please add some more details

Answer (score 0):

```js
elArray = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'];
dlArray = ['d4', 'd3', 'd2', 'd1'];

answer = "";

console.log("*****************************************");
console.log(elArray)
console.log(dlArray)
for (let i = 0; i < dlArray.length; i++) {
  answer += elArray[i];
  answer += ':';
  answer += dlArray[(dlArray.length - 1) - i];
  answer  += ' '
}
console.log(answer)
```

I made some assumptions as you did not provide some of the supporting details. As you can see here though I simply just subtracted the current `i` to get the reverse positioning.